# Route with controller action always throwing syntax error during Laravel Packages development

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am new in Laravel package development.Just trying to develop a simple package following the below tutorial:

https://devdojo.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-create-a-laravel-package

Everything is going well but some problem is arising when trying to add route with controller. Following route is working well .

```
Route::get('calculator', function(){
    echo 'Hello from the calculator package!';
});
```

But the following routes give the error shown below

```
Route::get('add/{a}/{b}', 'Devdojo\Calculator\CalculatorController@add');
Route::get('subtract/{a}/{b}', 'Devdojo\Calculator\CalculatorController@subtract');
```

> syntax error, unexpected 'Route' (T_STRING)" error.

Please anybody help me. 
Sorry for my weak English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to all the problem is solved.